# Getting unique items when there's a foreign key and a primary key? Repeated item (with unique weak key)?

Tags: sqlite, distinct, aggregate-functions

Here's my "data" for say, a ticket database for a city.

TABLE A
license_no

```
 12345
 12376
 88888
 99999
 64646
 77777
```

(Note: I know this is a superfluous table... pretend it has something else interesting. PRIMARY KEY: license_no)

TABLE B
license_no, date_of_offense, amount, city

```
 12345 09/12/15 200 New York
 12345 09/13/15 300 London
 12345 09/14/15 9999 London
 12345 09/20/2016 1000 London
 88888 12/12/2002 12 Frankfurt
 12376 01/01/2009 86 London
 99999 10/10/2012 19 St. Petersburg
 64646 10/10/2013 19 St. Petersburg
 77777 10/10/2011 20 St. Petersburg
```

(PRIMARY KEY: license_no, FOREIGN KEY, date_of_offense)

Now, if my problem is that I want to know which city has the most UNIQUE people ticketed? That would be St. Petersburg, but how do I isolate ID:12345 as distinct when I do this query, so that I'm not returning it as a result as well?

Assume that I won't always know that it's ID:12345, but am asking more generally using this as an example. I don't have the best understanding of these concepts and my professor hasn't been great at elaborating on them...

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You want to join on the basis of date_of_offense? Also license_no shoud be a foreign key in table B. then it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) says:

> In any aggregate function that takes a single argument, that argument can be preceded by the keyword DISTINCT. In such cases, duplicate elements are filtered before being passed into the aggregate function.

So you can just count licenses per city, and add DISTINCT:

```
SELECT city,
       count(DISTINCT license_no)
FROM B
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That makes some sense, but in terms of syntax, how would I then use that value of count?

Comment: Specifically, I need to test on a treatment by treatment basis which group has more distinct people in it, say, tickets > 100. Tickets > 200 etc.

Comment: The count value is the second column of the result. If you want to have it a name, use AS. You didn't ask for additional groups.

Comment: I know, but I had you here so I thought I'd inquire. Thank you for your help. Hopefully I can figure this out now.